# How to create a search results web page and store a large list of items without SQLDatabase

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I made a web page for selling items online. The website has a lot of products but will probably have multiple thousand products in the near future. The website contains a search bar and I want to create a search results page, but I am not sure what the best way of doing this is. I thought about using JavaScript to loop through the list of all the products until it finds a match. But this process is probably too slow. My question is: What is the best way to store a large list of items, and what is the best way to find matches from the list for the search query? I now that many people use SQL databases for storing lists but is that method any better than simply storing everything in a JavaScript list, and why? Also how do I find a match in the list? Can I use JavaScript or is it necessary or better to use a language like PHP?

Comment: Google "mysql full text search" and you'll be surprised how capable a database can be at searching.

Comment: You should use a database for storing and querying data. It is designed exactly for that purpose and is very efficient. Having you entire db in the form of a lists is not a good idea, it would be slow, very difficult to maintain and would cause a lot of security issues down the line.

Comment: If you do not want to create a back-end with SQL based DB then look into Firebase. It allows to create a Javascript based app without having to develop a back-end separately. You can create and manage your DB using javascript code in your front-end. It will provide you the functionality for searching, sorting and all the DB related operations.

Comment: Use an API and at backend do things efficiently and optimized 